# How do you use C# NetworkStream ReadAsync() to only grab stuff between stx and etx?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I'm trying to build a new application that communicates with another finished application over TCP/IP. The two applications pass messages back and forth between each other. Here is some of my server code from my new application that reads stuff in from the finished application:

```
public class AsyncService
{
    private IPAddress ipAddress;
    private int port;
    char[] STX = new char[] { '' };
    char[] ETX = new char[] { '' };
    NetworkStream networkStream;
    TcpClient tcpClient;
    private byte[] rawBuffer;

    private static readonly int RAWBUFFERSIZE = 2024;

    public AsyncService(int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
        string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
        rawBuffer = new byte[RAWBUFFERSIZE];
        this.ipAddress = IPAddress.Any;
        if (this.ipAddress == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("No IPv4 address for server");
        }
    }

    public async void Run()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(this.ipAddress, this.port);
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                tcpClient = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                DoReadAsync(rawBuffer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void DoReadAsync(byte[] byteBuffer)
    {
        Task<int> t = networkStream.ReadAsync(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
        t.ContinueWith((task, bytes) => OnReadCompleted((byte[])bytes, task.Result), byteBuffer, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    }

    private void OnReadCompleted(byte[] byteBuffer, int length)
    {
        if (length == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        string message = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(byteBuffer);

        //...

        Array.Clear(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
        DoReadAsync(byteBuffer);
    }
```

Every message sent is preceded with a STX character and ended with an ETX character. The problem is that there are times when my new application receives more than one message at a time. For example, I might receive a message like this:

[STX]123456789[ETX][STX]10111213141516171819[ETX]

I want to make my code so that I only read until I hit an ETX character. Thus, I would want the above example to be two messages but I don't know how to do that with ReadAsync(). Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: That's the way buffers work. You are reading what's in the buffer. It might be a whole message, two messages, half a message. You need to handle piecing it back together yourself.

Comment: If you define the message yourself it is often easier to have the first 4 bytes specify the length of the message so then read the next x bytes (as specified by the first four bytes) then once you have read that length read the next 4 bytes to get the next message length

Comment: The easy way to do this is switch to SignalR. :)

Comment: @StephenCleary can you provide resources regarding the use of signalR outside asp .net applications ?

Comment: @Bruno: [Here you go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host)

Comment: @StephenCleary Thank you. Does singlaR would be relevant in this scenario [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/369581/exposing-two-way-listening-endpoint-to-future-unknown-not-yet-developped-clients)

Comment: @Bruno: SignalR would be a good implementation choice. Consider restricting it to WebSockets. WebSockets should have pretty broad adoption across languages and platforms at this point. But if you want to be fully interoperable, you'd need to go REST or something like that, complete with safely-queued messages and polling - not very easy, but doable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you essentially have 2 choices. Read the whole stream into a string and then parse it, or parse the stream on the fly by reading it byte by byte and stopping when you reach your "magic" combo of bytes. Personally, if the datastream is not massive then option 1 will be much easier to achieve
hth

Comment: Are these 2 solutions something that is *in general* good to do (regarding best practices) and does the STX/ETX stuff is THE thing to do when implementing tcp socket? This is a really genuine network neewbie question and not at all a critic, as I'm facing the same kind of problem.